# Reading fixed width format text tables from HTML page

Tags: html, r, xml, web-scraping, tabular

I am trying to read data from tables similar to the following http://www.fec.gov/pubrec/fe1996/hraz.htm using **R** but have been unable to make progress.  I realize that to do so I need to use XML and RCurl but in spite of the numerous other examples on the web concerning similar problems I have not been able to resolve this one.

The first issue is that the table is only a table when viewing it but is not coded as such.  Treating it as an xml document I can access the "data" in the table but because there are several tables I would like to get I don't believe this to be the most elegant solution.

Treating it as an html document might work better but I am relatively unfamiliar with xpathApply and do not know how to get at the actual "data" in the table since it is not bracketed by anything (i.e. a i-/i or b-/b).

I have had some success using xml files in the past but this is my first attempt at doing something similar with html files.  These files in particular seem to have less structure then other examples I have seen.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Viewing the source of that page, that's not a table.

Comment: I think you want xml reader and not csv (table) reader

Comment: Looking at the source code of the page again, they have *tried* to present the data in a fixed width format, so you might be able to just "copy and paste" and use `read.fwf`. However. I mention that they have *tried* to make the data fixed width, but you can see that "District 3" is aligned differently from the others, which will require further cleanup after importing.

Comment: That page will bring even a good programmer to tears if he tries to parse it as table (even as FWF table)

Comment: this is a bit of a kludge but....  What about (1) printing the website to PDF  (2) OCR  (3) read in the OCR output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can read the `html` output into a text file (the equivalent of copying+pasting form your web browser), 
this should get you a good chunk of the way there:

```
# x is the output from the website 


library(stringr)
library(data.table)

# First, remove commas from numbers (easiest to do at beginning)
x <- gsub(",([0-9])", "\\1", x)

# split the data by District
districts <- strsplit(x, "DISTRICT *")[[1]]

# separate out the header info
headerInfo <- districts[[1]]
districts <- tail(districts, -1)


# grab the straggling district number, use it as a name and remove it 

    # end of first line
    eofl <- str_locate(districts, "\n")[,2]

    # trim white space and assign as name
    names(districts) <- str_trim(substr(districts, 1, eofl))

    # remove first line
    districts <- substr(districts, eofl+1, nchar(districts))

# replace the ending '-------' and trime white space
    districts <- str_trim(str_replace_all(districts, "---*", ""))

# Adjust delimeter (this is the tricky part)

    ## more than two spaces are a spearator
    districts <- str_replace_all(districts, "  +", "\t")

    ## lines that are total tallies are missing two columns. 
    ##   thus, need to add two extra delims. After the first and third columns

        # this function will 
        padDelims <- function(section, splton) {
          # split into lines
          section <- strsplit(section, splton)[[1]]
          # identify lines starting with totals
          LinesToFix <- str_detect(section, "^Total")
          # pad appropriate columns
          section[LinesToFix] <- sub("(.+)\t(.+)\t(.*)?", "\\1\t\t\\2\t\t\\3", section[LinesToFix])

          # any rows missing delims, pad at end
          counts <- str_count(section, "\t")
          toadd  <- max(counts) - counts
          section[ ] <- mapply(function(s, p) if (p==0) return (s) else paste0(s, paste0(rep("\t", p), collapse="")), section, toadd) 

          # paste it back together and return
          paste(section, collapse=splton)
        }

    districts <- lapply(districts, padDelims, splton="\n")

    # reading the table and simultaneously addding the district column
    districtTables <- 
       lapply(names(districts), function(d) 
         data.table(read.table(text=districts[[d]], sep="\t"), district=d) )
    # ... or without adding district number: 
    ##       lapply(districts, function(d) data.table(read.table(text=d, sep="\t")))

    # flatten it 
    votes <- do.call(rbind, districtTables)
    setnames(votes, c("Candidate", "Party", "PrimVotes.Abs", "PrimVotes.Perc", "GeneralVotes.Abs", "GeneralVotes.Perc", "District") )
```

Sample table:

```
 votes

                        Candidate      Party PrimVotes.Abs PrimVotes.Perc GeneralVotes.Abs GeneralVotes.Perc District
 1:                  Salmon, Matt          R         33672         100.00        135634.00             60.18        1
 2:            Total Party Votes:                    33672             NA               NA                NA        1
 3:                                                     NA             NA               NA                NA        1
 4:                     Cox, John     W(D)/D          1942         100.00         89738.00             39.82        1
 5:            Total Party Votes:                     1942             NA               NA                NA        1
 6:                                                     NA             NA               NA                NA        1
 7:         Total District Votes:                    35614             NA        225372.00                NA        1
 8:                    Pastor, Ed          D         29969         100.00         81982.00             65.01        2
 9:            Total Party Votes:                    29969             NA               NA                NA        2
10:                                                     NA             NA               NA                NA        2
...
51:                Hayworth, J.D.          R         32554         100.00        121431.00             47.57        6
52:            Total Party Votes:                    32554             NA               NA                NA        6
53:                                                     NA             NA               NA                NA        6
54:                  Owens, Steve          D         35137         100.00        118957.00             46.60        6
55:            Total Party Votes:                    35137             NA               NA                NA        6
56:                                                     NA             NA               NA                NA        6
57:              Anderson, Robert        LBT           148         100.00         14899.00              5.84        6
58:                                                     NA             NA               NA                NA        6
59:         Total District Votes:                    67839             NA        255287.00                NA        6
60:                                                     NA             NA               NA                NA        6
61:            Total State Votes:                   368185             NA       1356446.00                NA        6
                        Candidate      Party PrimVotes.Abs PrimVotes.Perc GeneralVotes.Abs GeneralVotes.Perc District
```